# PostgreSQL - include date

Tags: postgresql

I need to include today's date in my query.

```
SELECT *
FROM
    transactions, machine
WHERE
    transactions.machineid::int8 = machine.machineid::int8 AND
    (machine.storeid = '".$_SESSION['user_session']."')
```

In the transactions table is a date column.

Comment: I'm sorry: i *had* to add the sql-injection tag.(plus the PHP tag)

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-datetime.html

Comment: thanx for the documentation , also sql injection will be fixed

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM
transactions, machine
WHERE
transactions.machineid::int8 = machine.machineid::int8 AND
(machine.storeid = ? )
AND date = ?
```